# How do I make my layout look the same in all resolutions?

Tags: jquery, html, css, positioning

I'm just learning here and have tried all the different types of divs (absolute, relative, fixed, etc.) but I'm really having trouble figuring this out.

This is the website I'm working on: http://www.chelseyburch.com

On my computer, at 1366 x 768, it looks exactly how I want it to. But when I try on any other resolution or change the browser size there is a huge amount of space between the header and the slider. Also, with the gallery carousel sliders (on the people, places, things links) there is a lot of space in between the images.

I'm sorry if this seems like a stupid question, but I'm really having difficulty figuring out how to make it look the same across all resolutions.

This is what it looks like. I know it's all over the place, this is why I'm asking for help. Thanks in advance.

```
#header {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin: 30px;
}

#social {
    float: right;
    position: fixed;
    top: 30px;
    right: 0;
    margin: 5px;
}

#slidy-container {
    width: 100%; 
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.jcarousel-wrapper {
    height: 480px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you heard about [CSS3 Media queries](http://cssmediaqueries.com/)? explore it :)

Comment: It's technically "CSS" Media queries.  They will work with any browser.  Not just CSS3 browsers.

Comment: The Stuff that you are doing is called as Responsive Web Design .. http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-responsive-web-design-cross-browser-compatibility/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have the `#slidy-container` positioned absolute and placed to the bottom with `bottom:0`. Try to change it to:

```
#slidy-container {
  width: 100%; 
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 130px; /* change this value to your header height */
}
```

However this only works for resolutions bigger than 800px. If you need lower resolution, try a media query and create a new css-layout for resolutions under 800px:

```
@media (min-width: 800px) {
    #slidy-container {
        top: 300px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I originally wanted it to be at the bottom on the screen but I'm willing to sacrifice it. Is this just because of the size of the images that there was such a large space? In my resolution the slider spread from the bottom to right underneath the header.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#slidy-container{
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 150px;  /* this is the line I changed */
}
```

I removed the bottom, which is messing it up on different resolutions, and replaced with top: 150px.

Comment: Thanks very much. I originally wanted it to be at the bottom on the screen but I'm willing to sacrifice it. Is this just because of the size of the images that there was such a large space? In my resolution the slider spread from the bottom to right underneath the header